# Android Dynamically Creating Preferences, how to commit?

Tags: android, preference

I am creating an app where the user is asked to store contacts from the contact list. I am dynamically creating a preference object for each contact (using the title for the name and the summary for the phone number) and adding them to a preference category (because I like the way they look). When I leave the that screen it disappears. I figure I am forgetting to use a commit function?

Below is my addContact method:

```
private void addContact(String contactName, String contactPhone)
{
    Log.i(TAG,"In Function: addContact");

    if(isDuplicateContact(contactName,contactPhone)){ //Check is duplicate
        Log.i(TAG,"Contact Already Exists");
        Toast.makeText(this,"Contact Already in List", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          
    }
    else{
        Log.i(TAG,"Add new Contact");

        PreferenceCategory targetCategory = (PreferenceCategory)findPreference("contact_category");
        Preference newContact = new Preference(this); 
        newContact.setKey("contact_"+contactName.replaceAll("\\s",""));
        newContact.setTitle(contactName);
        newContact.setSummary(contactPhone);
        newContact.setLayoutResource(R.layout.contact_pref_layout);

        noContactMethod(); //Check if there is no contact, if not replace with No Contact
        targetCategory.addPreference(newContact);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding contacts to the preference category just adds them visually.

I don't know if you can save them as a collection after you add them, but
I do know you can save them individually as follows:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager
.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity()).edit();

editor.putString("key", "value");
editor.commit();
```